# How to remove rows that contain various types of dates in a mixed-type column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample of my data and there are multiple types in the column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['01/03/1987', 'May-1', 'Jan-08', '10-Feb', '2/13/2016','2-13-2016', 99.98, 'a text', 'text00', 10, -9, 4-5]})
```

I think I've listed all formats of date. How can I remove the date from the column if I can use regexp?

Result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[99.98, 'a text', 'text00', 10, -9, 4-5]})
```

Comment: why do you have so many varying date formats in a single column ?

Comment: You probably will have to write your own function that can detect these dates depending on what other values can you expect in the column. For example, can you assume that all other texts will not have numbers in them?

Answer (score 1):

if you have varying date formats then a simple `str.contains` could work

```
con = df['A'].str.contains('/|-')
df[(con.isna()) | (con==False)]
```

---

```
        A
6   99.98
7  a text
8    text
9      10
```

Comment: Thank you. The original data are from a medical system which is very complicated. This column records lab measurements of patients. It just includes all test results in one column.  Actually, I want to use regex to solve that because I notice there are some values containing '-', like -10, 2-3.